# Setting up addon domain with co.cc

Tags: domain-name, settings

I have a x10hosting free account and created add-on(co.cc) domain, I have set up co.cc account to work for google apps , Now I want to point domain name to x10hosting account , On x10 hosting control panel shared Ip is 69.162.111.26. So I pointed my co.cc A record of .co.cc to 69.162.111.26, I just want to know is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is correct.

I assume if you are using this domain for google apps then you have pointed your MX records to googles servers? If thats the case your good.